# ffmpeg cutting the last 2 seconds of audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

When I record both audio and video using ffmpeg the audio recording cuts out for the last two seconds of the video.

```
 ffmpeg \
     -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 \
     -f alsa -i hw:2 \
     samples/video.mp4
```

I have tried using different audio and video codecs, as well as different video formats and I, have noticed that mpg format instead of mp4 the audio works better.

I have also tried using different codecs with the mp4 and checked the compatibilities [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_file_format) but they don't seem to matter much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So adding the following line seems to solve the problem.

```
-preset ultrafast -threads 0
```